# Unhandeld Exception only in Windows 7 on installing Windows application

Tags: windows-7

I have windows application developed in VB.NET
Visual Studio 2008
.NET Framework 3.5
SQL Server 2005 Express Edition
The application has a setup project, on clicking the setup.exe the setup runs and the application gets installed on the user’s machine
The setup checks for the existence on SQL Server 2005 Express Edition in user’s machine, if it is not present then it installs the SQL Server 2005 Express edition.
The application works fine on Windows XP and Vista, but it is not working fine on Windows 7, after the set is run on windows 7 the “Unhandled exception” occurs.
Exception details are
************** Exception Text **************
    System.IO.IOException: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
at System.IO.FileInfo.MoveTo(String destFileName)
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Does right clicking Setup.exe and run as administrator have the same problem?

Otherwise you can set a value in the registry and use DebugView to get a debug trace like:
http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q106954

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer]
Debug DWORD to 2